# How to set timeout for Java Wireless Toolkit generated web service calls?

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me, timeout

I have used the Java Wireless Toolkit Stub Generator to create a bunch of web service call stubs for a mobile app (BlackBerry J2ME app). The problem I'm having is that there doesn't appear to be any way to set a timeout on the calls. This causes the app to sit and wait for at least a minute waiting to timeout if the web service that is called is offline. I'd really like to set this timeout to something more manageable and then handle the offline situation.

The code generated uses javax.microedition.xml.rpc.Operation.Invoke to make the actual calls, but there is no timeout property anywhere that I can find.

Comment: So how did you integrate timeout condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no timeout property in standard [jsr 172](http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/JSR_172_Web_Services_Specification_1_0/).
Try to set a timer to terminate connection thread if there was no response, handle exception and maintain offline case.

Comment: You're welcome! I know it's bad. Hope there will be alternatives in future.